# How to intercept private methods

Tags: java, interceptor, cglib

Can someone please explain how some mocking libraries like power mock create proxies for private method. I looked a little into **cglib** but couldn't find a way to **intercept private method invocation**. I specifically want to know about any **low level libraries** or core java techniques that can be used to intercept private methods.

Comment: I think this question has the answer to your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776369/interception-of-package-private-method-for-jdk-class-with-cglib

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to intercept the call as such. Just(!) insert your code at the start of the method. (Requires a bit of fixing up for the rest of the code.) Code can be rewritten at class load time through the Java Agent API.

Having siad that, IMO for testing you are much better off splitting into smaller classes and your seam is for free.